# Certificate Signature invalidates and Signature with revision (2) Validates. Using iTextsharp 5.5.13

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

```csharp
    var PdfXPosition = Convert.ToSingle(finalString[j].Split(',')[1].Trim().Replace('"', ' ').Trim()) - .00220f;
    var PdfYPosition = Convert.ToSingle(finalString[j].Split(',')[2].Trim().Replace('"', ' ').Trim()) - 33.00000f;
    Image Sign = Image.GetInstance(SignatureImagePath);
    Sign.SetAbsolutePosition(PdfXPosition, PdfYPosition);
    Sign.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    stamper.GetOverContent(1).AddImage(Sign);
    appearance.Image = Sign;
    appearance.SignDate=Convert.ToDateTime(indianTime);

    //appearance.SignDate = Convert.ToDateTime("19-06-2022 12:53:28 AM");
    //appearance.CryptoDictionary = pdfSignature;

    if (ApproversCount == "1")
    {
        stamper.Writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_4;
        //appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING;// CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS;
    }
    else {
        stamper.Writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_3;
        appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING;// CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS;
    }
   
    //For Invisible Signature make Height and Width to zero                                    
    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1,"Sign"+ guid);
    // stamper.AddSignature("Sign" + obj, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

IExternalSignature externalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(akp, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512);
MakeSignatures.SignDetachedd(appearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. From the title I'd deduce that sometimes the created signature is invalid. But details are completely amiss.

Comment: Two observations, though: **(1)** You add an image to the static content of the first page (`stamper.GetOverContent(1).AddImage(Sign)`). This is forbidden if previous signatures exist. Add the image as part of a signature appearance instead. **(2)** In case of certification you try to change the PDF version to 1.3 (`stamper.Writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_3`). This is critical as certification signatures have not been in the PDF Reference before PDF 1.5.